# Add conditional CSS property in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to add conditional CSS property to a div in such a way that if particular condition is true then only it will applied. Below is my code.

```
const Select = ({
  handleClick,
  title,
  permission,
}: SelectProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{
        marginTop: '16px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        pointerEvents   <-- make this property conditional
        ${({ permission }) => permission && `pointerEvents: none;`}  <-- tried this but not working
      }}
    >
      <Title>{title}</Title>
    </div>
  );
};

export const RenderSelectBlock = () => {
  const checkUserPermission = checkUserPermission();
  return (
    <Select
     handleClick={() => setSelectType('Google')}
     title="Google"
     checkUserPermission={checkUserPermission}
    />
    <Select
     handleClick={() => setSelectType('Microsoft')}
     title="Microsoft"
     checkUserPermission={checkUserPermission}
    />
    <Select
     handleClick={() => setSelectType('Apple')}
     title="Apple"
     checkUserPermission={checkUserPermission}
    />
    <Select
     handleClick={() => setSelectType('Facebook')}
     title="Facebook"
     checkUserPermission={checkUserPermission}
    />
  )
);
};
```

So here in the last `Select` where `title` is `Facebook`, I want to disable it if the user don't have permission i.e. `permission = false`. Basically `pointerEvents` property should only be added for `title= Facebook` and should be set to `none` if `permission = false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You best option is to avoid `style` entirely and use `className`, then include a second class (maybe `no-pointer-events`) for the `pointer-events` you want to optionally include:

```
<div
    className={`main-class ${permission ? "no-pointer-events" : ""}`}
```

But if you want to do it with `style`, you could use `undefined` for when you don't want to specify it:

```
<div
    style={{
        marginTop: '16px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        pointerEvents: permission ? "none" : undefined,
    }}
```

You could also define the style object before reaching this point in the code:

```
const style = {
    marginTop: '16px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
};
if (permission) {
    style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

Then use it:

```
<div
    style={style}
```

Sometimes you'll see people do this with multiple properties via spread syntax:

```
<div
    style={{
        marginTop: '16px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        ...(permission ? {pointerEvents: "none"} : undefined),
    }}
```

`...undefined` is fine in an object literal (it doesn't add any properties).