# How to add css propety only variable is. true ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add css property if value is true. Example ->

```
  menuList: (styles, { selectProps }) => ({
    ...styles,
    padding: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    maxHeight: selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown && "120px"
  }),
```

And this is work. Also i am try with

```
  menuList: (styles, { selectProps }) => ({
    ...styles,
    padding: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    maxHeight: selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown ? "120px" : "
  }),
```

But in every time maxHeight proerty is setted.

What I need ?

If selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown === true set maxHeigh

If selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown === false  not set **maxHeigh**

What i am try

```
  menuList: (styles, { selectProps }) => ({
    ...styles,
    padding: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown ? maxHeight: selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown 
   "120px" : '
  }),
```

But this is can't be written.

Comment: Use obj & spread syntax eg: `...(permission ? {pointerEvents: "none"} : undefined),` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954549/add-conditional-css-property-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create another object.

```js
const dynamicStyles = {};
if(selectProps.setShortHeightDropDown) {
  dynamicStyles.maxHeight = "120px";
}
// maybe some more if statements for some other dynamic props
```

Then add it to the original object:

```js
menuList: (styles, { selectProps }) => ({
  ...styles,
  padding: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  ...dynamicStyles
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1 - Template Literal

I'd recommend putting the conditional CSS properties into a class and then adding/removing this class from the target element based on your value:

e.g.

*styles.css* (or wherever your styles are)

```
.dynamic-styles {
    // Styles go here
}
```

*app.js* (or wherever your component is)

```
import './styles.css'; // Don't forget to import your stylesheet

function YourComponent(props) {
    ...
    const value = // Compute from props, state or otherwise
    ...
    return (
        <div className={`basic-class ${value ? 'dynamic-styles' : ''}`.trim()}>
            ...
        </div>
    );

}
```

### Approach 2 - Computed ClassList

In more complex scenarios where you have multiple different dynamic classes, you could abstract this into a memoised value using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) ([`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList)):

```
    ...
    const className = useMemo(() => {
        const classList = new DOMTokenList();
        classList.add('basic-class');

        if (value === 'value-a') classList.add('dynamic-class-a')
        else if (value === 'value-a') classList.add('dynamic-class-b')

        return classList.toString();
    }, [value]);
    
    return (
        <div className={className}>
    ...
```

The use of `useMemo` here ensures the `className` is only computed when the dependent values change. [Read more about it on the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).